# Comparing corresponding rows from the same column and same table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table structure is:

Customers(customerid,first name,last name,state)

I want to print the name of  the customers who belong to the same state and if they are from states where no other customer lives then that customer should be omitted..I tried inner joins but couldn't get the exact results I get one or more extra rows.

Comment: Can't you use a GROUP BY clause? Or do you want it done for a specific state specified at runtime?

Comment: @crnlx I cant use a group by because I need to select the customerid of those who belong to the same state and compare it with cid from another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is from Access SQL, which should work fine for you.

```
Select customer_id, state, last_name, first_name
FROM Customers
WHERE (((state) In (Select state FROM Customers GROUP BY state HAVING (((Count(state))>1)))))
ORDER BY state,last_name, first_name
```